# How to implement interface method with generic

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, overriding

```
public interface A {
  public void setStar(Star star)
}

public class A-Class implements A {
 public void setStar(StarImpl star)
}

public interface Star {
}

public class StarImpl implements Star {
}
```

So basically, I want to apply interface A to A-Class. But it gives me error: `A-Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method setStar(Star)`.

I know the reason is that `setStar()` in A-class is not exact as the one in interface A. But I don't know how to use generic to fix it? Any ideas? Thanks you very much!

What I tried:

```
public class A-Class implements A {
 public void setStar(<? extends Star> star)
}

public class A-Class implements A {
 public <T extends Star> void setStar(T star)
}
```

Both of them doesn't work. Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: change name of A-Class. There is something wrong with your details. Error should be `A-Class is not abstract and does ..`

Comment: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2970947)

Comment: @Ravi Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Does it mean I need to change the interface into superclass?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do; read that link again. It tells you when you need `extends`, `super` or neither. You told us it doesn't work, not what you want it to do...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Really appreciate for your quick response! Basically, I want to make the interface A used in two classes, where it needs to implement those method to accept two type of class (both of them are implemented from interface Star).

Comment: Then should not `Star` itself be generic? Please post a MCVE. I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: Do  you mean make the interface `Star` as generic? Is it possible for you to give an example?

Comment: It looks like PECS is only for class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface A<T extends Star> {
  public void setStar(T star)
}
```

After some trying, I solved the problem by myself. Basically, it's to add generic to interface A. Thanks, guys!